# Run shell command in GoLang within windows CMD

Tags: go, cloud-foundry

I am trying to execute cloudfoundry CF Client from my GoLang. The `cf login` command usually will not get executed in my git-bash terminal / cygwin terminal. It gets executed **properly only in Command-Prompt** (CMD.exe). So I always do `cf login` command from my CMD.exe only.

Now i attempted to execute the command from GoLang and found that it is executing in cygwin / git-bash pattern and give me the below error as output

```
API endpoint: https://api.sys-pcf.cf.MYCOMPANY.com
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
```

I get the same error when i execute cf login from cygwin.  Below is my Go code

```
    cf :="cf"
    login := "login"
    sso := "--sso"
    apiFlag := "-a"

    command := exec.Command(cf,login,sso,apiFlag,foundationUrl)


    stdout, err := command.Output()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error")
    }

    fmt.Print(string(stdout))
```

Please tell me how to execute these commands in windows-style or through command-prompt

The os.exec package link [here](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/)  tells that

*Unlike the "system" library call from C and other languages, the os/exec package intentionally does not invoke the system shell*

*Note that the examples in this package assume a Unix system. They may not run on Windows, and they do not run in the Go Playground used by golang.org and godoc.org.*

I think the exec package by itself doesn't support windows shell

Comment: How are you running your code ? My best guess is that your native console and cygwin don't share the same PATH, hence the client failing to connect. Therefore, if you are running your golang program from a cygwin console, it will share the same issue.
Alternatively, if you know why the client only execute properly in a native shell, another solution would be to solve this problem instead.

Comment: `fmt.Println(err)` will not work here because the command-execution doesn't through any error, whereas the `cf login` is getting rejected

Comment: There are lot of discussions going on to identify why CF LOGIN is not working in CYGWIN mode. There is no concrete solution for this. It works only in command-prompt. So we will have to instruct GoLang to execute this in Command-Prompt style

Comment: what is cf? cf login
'cf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: cf is a cloud foundry CLI tool https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli

Comment: Cygwin & Git Bash on Windows have some known issues with the cf cli (in particular `cf login`) at this time -> https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli#known-issues